# Is it possible in Intune to set up this policy that every time a user wants to download,copy & delete something,the admin has to get the notification

Tags: endpoint, sccm, intune

1. Is it possible in Microsoft Intune to set up this  policy  that every time a user wants to download, copy, or delete something, the admin has to get the notification?
2. Is it possible to prevent the user from installing any app or software unless the admin grants permission? If the user wants to install something, the admin must grant permission.

If anyone has knowledge on these two types of policies, please send the required settings. It will be so helpful for me.

I tried using the AppLocker but it is blocking ever app installation so I need customized restriction

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in Microsoft Intune to set up this policy that every time a user wants to download, copy, or delete something, the admin has to get the notification?

On mobile devices, you can block downloads or copies by application protection policy (same for W10). Or if you have a license for DLP, you can use the technology to audit events. Don't forget the cloud apps.

> Is it possible to prevent the user from installing any app or software unless the admin grants permission? If the user wants to install something, the admin must grant permission.

We don't use this option but in device configuration, there is some restriction option that can block these features